# setting directory alias for window command

Tags: cmd

I have few working directory that is in use often and I notice that it is quite troublesome to always cd between this directory.

```
cd "C:\FolderA\FolderAA\FolderAAA"
```

I want to achieve something like this. (it should be persistent).

```
set alias "C:\FolderA\FolderAA\FolderAAA" "FolderAAA"
cd alias "FolderAAA"
```

How can this be achieve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apply [`DOSKEY.EXE`](https://ss64.com/nt/doskey.html):

> Recall and edit commands at the `CMD` prompt, and create macros. You
>   cannot run a Doskey macro from a batch file.
>
> Syntax
>
> ```
> DOSKEY [options] [macroname=[text]]
> ```
>
> Key
>
> ```
> macroname   A short name for the macro.
>
>      text   The commands you want to recall.
> ```

Example:

```
doskey FolderAAA=cd "C:\FolderA\FolderAA\FolderAAA"
FolderAAA
```

**Another approach**:

Set a `CMD` environment variable. Note that changes made with [`SET`](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html) will remain only for the duration of the **current `CMD` session**.

```
set "FolderAAA=C:\FolderA\FolderAA\FolderAAA"
cd "%FolderAAA%"
```

To set an environment variable permanently, use [`SETX.EXE`](https://ss64.com/nt/setx.html).

> `SETX` can be used to set Environment Variables for the machine
>   (`HKLM`) or currently logged on user (`HKCU`):

```
setx FolderAAA C:\FolderA\FolderAA\FolderAAA
```

> Because `SETX` writes variables to the master environment in the
>   registry, edits will only take effect when a new command window is
>   opened - they do not affect the current CMD or PowerShell session.

Comment: An environment variable or batch script is more reliable. doskey.exe doesn't create CMD aliases. It creates console aliases. The nice thing about them is they can be customized for each console application. The bad thing is that they only match at the start of a line when reading from console input, so they can't be used anywhere else such as the right-hand side of a pipe or in a batch script.

Comment: thanks @josefz , I also added this in my env vars to make the change permanent. whenever I call %pr% from any cmd prompt, It switches to the directory that I selected.